# Link to another item in a sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint

I am writing a custom Sharepoint solution and I have to fulfill a requirement that an item in 1 document library must be visiable in another document library, e.g. maintaining global company document which should display in all other librarys

I need to sync properties, e.g. name so that when it changes in the source list it should also change in the destination lists. The items created in the destination list should not be able to have workflows or other options in the ECB Menu (exception for maybe going to source document).

Does anyone have a realistic solution on how to accomplish this ?

I have been trying to use CopyIntoItems of the copy web service to create linked copies with no luck, it always just creates a new copy of the source item (see: http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/sharepoint-moss-creating-document-library-items-uploading-files-to-a-document-library/)

Creating a custom content type has also entered my mind (since the source properties is contained in a content type) but then how do I filter the ECB menu ?

Answer (score 2):

If the destination document library is a replica of the source document library, can't you solve this by displaying the items on the destination side using a content query web part instead of duplicating the items?

Comment: I would agree. Don't have actual copies everywhere. You bog the system down with space requirements and system events needlessly. Plus who knows what effect this has on your crawler as your index will have duplicate entries. Your best bet would be to have a master library and then make use of a query everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I agree,it would be a mistake copy-ing the data all over the place. I'll take a close look at the content query web part.

The solution I am thinking about now is creating an ECB menu item to redirect to a custom page.From there the user can enter which document libraries he wants to display the document,in a button there a custom list is populated which contains reference between target document library and a source document. Then I will overwrite the template for the items .aspx pages to contain a web part with the external document.

More research is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

In the process for googling for something else I might have come across the solution to your problem.

Apparently Sharepoint has a built in 'linked document' type.  You can just use that to link the documents, instead of copying.

More info [here](http://www.sharepointproconnections.com/Articles/tabid/149/nodeid/839/Linking-to-documents-in-another-document-library.aspx).